# Why can springs HttpHeaders not be mocked?

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock

I have a class which uses the org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders class. While trying to unit test my class, the HttpHeaders can not be mocked. I have tried:

```
@Mock
HttpHeaders httpHeadersMock;
```

And

```
HttpHeaders httpHeadersMock = PowerMock.createMock(HttpHeaders.class);
```

And

```
HttpHeaders httpHeadersMock = EasyMock.createMock(HttpHeaders.class);
```

When running my test the httpHeadersMock shows the following in debug-mode:

> httpHeadersMock =  {HttpHeaders$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ef5766ff@1370}
>   Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw
>   'java.lang.IllegalStateException' exception.

Why does this happen and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: It appears it does get mocked. But the variable members are not available. Probably has something to do with this.

Comment: Post a complete example reproducing the problem. But that said, I don't really see why you want to mock this class, instead of just populating with the headers you want.